# Convert NSString to NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, type-conversion, nsindexpath

Essentially what I want to do is convert an NSString to a NSIndexPath.  When I use S3 to get an object I need to use the requestTag property which takes an NSString.  I use this tag to determine which object has finished downloading and therefore which activity indicator to stop spinning.  Below is partial code.  How can I turn the NSString requestTag into an NSIndexPath?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell viewWithTag:103];

if (![self.activityIndictatorOn containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [self.activityIndictatorOn addObject:indexPath];
    [activityView startAnimating];

...
    getObjectRequest.requestTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath];
}



-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{

NSLog(@"DOWNLOAD COMPLETE");


[self stopActivityIndicator:request.requestTag];
[self.downloadFinished addObject:request.requestTag];
}



 -(void)stopActivityIndicator:(NSString *)rowAtIndexPath
{
//Need to convert rowAtIndexPath to NSIndexPath
//Following line results in warning
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:rowAtIndexPath];
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
[activityView stopAnimating];
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath]
```

uses the `description` method to convert the index path to a string
of the form

```
{length = 2, path = <section> - <row>}
```

which is a bit difficult to parse back to an index path.

I would therefore suggest to convert the index path to the request string
of the format `section:row` with

```
NSString *requestTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
```

Then you can easily convert it back with

```
NSArray *tmp = [requestTag componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[tmp[1] integerValue] inSection:[tmp[0] integerValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can convert `indexPath` to `NSString` and set to `requestTag` as following:

```
     getObjectRequest.requestTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld,%ld", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

Then convert it back to `NSIndexPath` as given below:

```
    NSArray *rowIndexArray = [rowAtIndexPath componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:rowIndexArray[1] inSection:rowIndexArray[0]];
```